# Is it possible to access java thread's stack frame in its runtime data area?

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, stack-trace

We can use Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() to get the current stackTrace. But the StackTraceElement contains only a few information, such as class name, method name, line number, etc, which are just static informaiton. I want more runtime data. I'd like to access the method parameters values stored in current thread's stack frame. Is this possible? Thanks a lot!

Add some background of this question. I am trying to print out each stack frame's method parameter values when an exception is caught (ie. each stack frame in the stackTrace).
Is this possible? I read about java virtual machine that when the function is returned(normally or abrupt completion with exception), the current stack frame will be popped out. So I think even it's possible to access stack frame, we can only access the ones whose stack frame are still in the stack. Am I right?

AOP might solve this problem. With AOP I can do some code inject to save each method's parameter values before hand. When exception happens, I can look up the saved info. But I think this might not be the best solution regarding performance concern.

Comment: Not directly, no, and this would be a security risk. You can use debuggers and JVM agents, though. What is it you're trying to get done?

Comment: @chrylis, I added some background of my question. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stack frames in java are accessible using java debug architecture, which means you may use debuggers. Although your requirement may introduce a security threat as you want to access methods parameters outside its scope.

If you do eagerly want it to print at runtime rather than going for debuggers, One way I could think of is better create a bean info and set all info for a single method into it. You can store them in an ordered collection across methods and print them on exception.

AOP is also fine.

But, it all seems too much for achieving so little. May be more clarity on your purpose would help.